# How to autorun Office 365 outlook add-in

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm creating an Office 365 add-in for Outlook. I want my add-in to run automatically when user reads email (opens it in reading pane).

My current version displays add-in name in top of mail body and when I click it add-in runs.

```js
Office.initialize = function (reason) { 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        displayItemDetails();
    });
};
```

I would also like to hide that add-in button and just run it behind the scene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Office Add-In platform does not currently allow apps to auto-launch themselves in the way you're describing. Feel free to request this functionality on the [Office Extensibility Platform's UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-add-in-outlook).

Gabriel Royer

Developer on the Office Extensibility Team, MSFT

Comment: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/10770030-autorun-outlook-add-ins?tracking_code=272a72cf4adf3310a7b3814b1234bce7

Answer (score 1):

Auto-launching Outlook add-ins is not supported today.

What is your scenario? There may be a different way to achieve it.

Comment: I want to collect statistical information from emails which user receives. I know there is a own service for that also, but its not accurate enough.

Comment: what kind of information? typically developers use tracking pixels to get info whether the user read the message, etc

Comment: My Scenario would be the ability to configure rules externally. for example get the body of the email - run it against an externally configured list of customers and highlight in the email any sharepoint sites we have for those customers.

Comment: you can do this from the backend using REST APIs. You can subscribe to push notifications (web hooks) and find out when new messages are sent to a user. then grab the message, analyze is and mark it up.

Comment: Did you create a uservoice request for this? We want the same thing (though for composing new messages)

Comment: Yeah, but it was little different than just autorun: http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/10085988-allow-app-to-run-in-background-without-user-intera

I will vote your idea also.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, new information:

While not quite "auto-launching", Outlook now supports pinning an add-in. When an add-in supports [pinnable taskpane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane), the user is provided the option "pin" the add-in open. As the user moves between mail items, the pinned add-in will automatically load within the new mail item's context.